# How to write makefile for a target that includes a header file?

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, gnu-make

I have two files "create-exercise.cpp" and "exercise.hpp". I want to write a makefile to use gnu++17 and g++ to compile them. exercise.hpp is included in create-exercise.cpp. I only want to get a binary out of create-exercise.cpp. the command I would use is `g++ -std=gnu++17 create-exercise.cpp -o create-exercise` and it works well. I tried using the following in a make file.

```
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -std=gnu++17

create-exercise: create-exercise.cpp exercise.hpp
```

but that generated the following `g++ -Wall -std=gnu++17    create-exercise.cpp exercise.hpp   -o create-exercise` I don't want `exercise.hpp` to be included in the compilation command. I also tried to use the following instead.

```
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -std=gnu++17

create-exercise.o: create-exercise.cpp exercise.hpp
```

That generated `g++ -Wall -std=gnu++17 -c -o create-exercise.o create-exercise.cpp`. I don't want the `-c` flag. because when I try to run `create-exercise.o` that results in permission denied error. I tried the following as well:

```
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -std=gnu++17

create-exercise.o: create-exercise.cpp exercise.hpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) create-exercise.cpp -o create-exercise.o
```

but when I edit `exercise.hpp` make says `'create-exercise.o' is up to date.` and doesn't recompile it. what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule to write in your makefile would be:

```
create-exercise.o: exercise.hpp
```

This is a rule without a recipe, and it simply adds one more prerequisite (`exercise.hpp`) to the target `create-exercise.o`, i.e., whenever `exercise.hpp` changes, `create-exercise.o` should be rebuilt.

However, the problem when providing that rule is that GNU Make assumes `create-exercise.o` is an object file generated from a C source file when building `create-exercise`. Therefore, it doesn't link the C++ library but the C library instead, that's why you are having the liking error of undefined reference to `std::cout`.

GNU Make has the following implicit rule for generating an executable from a C++ source file:

```
%: %.cpp
#  commands to execute (built-in):
   $(LINK.cpp) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

You can use that rule's recipe to build `create-exercise` from `creating-exercise.o` and still treat `creating-exercise.o` as an object file that was generated from a C++ source file:

```
create-exercise: create-exercise.o
    $(LINK.cpp) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

The whole makefile would be then:

```
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -std=gnu++17 

create-exercise: create-exercise.o
    $(LINK.cpp) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

create-exercise.o: exercise.hpp
```

The target `create-exercise` also becomes the default goal because it's the first rule in the makefile. It's the target to build if you don't specify any to `make`.

Comment: I tried both both snippets but didn't work. the generated command was `cc create-exercise.o  -o  create-exercise`. here is a [github gist](https://gist.github.com/kerolloz/8db160b7ec23b9e88ea3bbf9e73216bf) with the two files if you want to try.

Comment: @kerolloz What is the problem?

Comment: the following error appears https://pastebin.com/raw/1yR0veRW

Comment: yes compiling `create-exercise.cpp` with `g++ -Wall -std=gnu++17  create-exercise.cpp -o create-exercise` works fine and I use the executable normally. I don't need to compile `exercise.hpp`. when I try to compile `exercise.hpp`, it doesn't work but I know why, because I didn't include `iostream` however I don't need it in `exercise.hpp` because it's already included in `create-exercise.cpp` and I don't need to use `exercise.hpp` separately.

Comment: @kerolloz I think I've found the issue. It was linking against the C library. See my edit.

Comment: that worked properly thank you for your time. I have a small question. I wonder why when I remove the touch statement it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @kerolloz `touch` changes the modification time of the file. if you remove the recipe (i.e., the `touch` command), it just means "`create-exercise.cpp` needs the file `exercise.hpp` to be built", as long as `exercise.hpp` exists everything is fine, whereas, with the recipe, it means "if `exercise.hpp` is newer than `create-exercise.o`, then `create-exercise.cpp` is outdated". The recipe is then executed to update `create-exercise.cpp`. This outdatedness propagates to `create-exercise.o` and `create-exercise`.

Comment: This is really not the right way to do it.  There is no need whatsoever to touch source files.

Comment: @kerolloz It is as I initially explained with the rule for `create-exercise.o: exercise.hpp`. However, that was causing the linking to be done with the C library instead. Now, it's properly linking to the C++ library. That with the `touch` was a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -std=gnu++17

create-exercise: create-exercise.o
        $(LINK.cpp) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

create-exercise.o: exercise.hpp
```

This says: build `create-exercise` from the object file `create-exercise.o`, if it's changed.  And it says rebuild `create-exercise.o` if the header file `exercise.hpp` changes; it's not right to modify or rebuild a *source file* if a header changes.  It's the *object file* that depends on the header.

Make has a number of built in rules.  Among them are rules that know how to link a program but unfortunately that assumes your object files were built from C files, so if you're using C++ you have to create a specific recipe.  But you can still use GNU make's default variables.

It also knows how to build a `.o` file from a `.cpp` file on its own: you don't need to write that recipe.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I expressed initially, the problem was that GNU Make was treating the `create-exercise.o` as an object generated from a C file and linking to the C library.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but maybe try to include the .hpp file instead of compiling it with the other file. You can do so by using g++ ***.cpp -I ***.hpp -o output

Try it out and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: `-I` specifies include *folders*, not header files.